# Can php and C++ run on the same server and communicate in a web site?

Tags: php, c++, webserver

I have a client that wishes to have a website written that involves a fairly simple cms driven website that sorts and displays daily reports. The website will require subscriptions and include membership, free trials, etc...

Originally I was going to write the site in PHP, as none of the requirements are too heavy and I am very experienced in it. However, after speaking with the client, he has worked closely with someone who has a C++ product that offers a workflow that includes the entire process of handling subscriptions, logins, and trials and (apparently) can be used on a web platform.

This throws a wrench into my original plan, because even though I know C++ I have never had to deploy it on a webserver or have it communicate with PHP. I've already written a good deal of the site in PHP, so would prefer not having to re-write.

Can I have the two communicate on the same server? What would be required to do so? Would it be worth my time or should I just decide to scrap PHP and use C++? Or should I tell my client he's nuts?

That's about all the info I have about the project right now. Not sure if I can provide much more info, but will try if it's needed.

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Probably. First of all, almost any general purpose programming language can do almost anything, and certainly C and C++ can do everything that PHP can do, because ultimately, PHP itself is written in C (and C++ can do everything C can do, it just takes more `<>` ;) ). Without knowing how/what the C++ application does, it's almost impossible to say exactly what you can and can't do with it, and whether it can or can't interface (easily) with PHP.

Comment: I suggest u find out more about the c++ product, and if you are building from scratch, i would still suggest using php, from a maintainability point of view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tel him he is nuts.

The reason is that none of those tasks requires the benefits C++ can offer over PHP. It is heavy maintenance pain. And in the big picture putting those two together is more work (in hours) than writing those things in php.

The only thing that would justify C++ is if there is some heavy math business logic involved in there. And i mean **heavy**.

For problems. Just think about debugging.

Comment: I was hoping this was the answer I would get. The reason he is asking in the first place is because he is clueless. This was my impression, I just wanted to double-check before giving that answer. I think I will just need a PHP plug-in handy that does the same thing and is either inexpensive or cheap.

Comment: As counter-argument, if there is an already existing solution that does most of what you need, it could mean "very little development work". As someone who is quite good at both C++ and PHP, I'd say if you have a sufficient set of fundamental code in C++, it's not a huge amount of effort to write in C++ either. You are basically just putting the lego bricks together, and sometimes you may even have complete chunks of existing code ready to use. But C++ is a lower level language, and if you write code from scratch, PHP is much easier, as it does a lot for you.

Comment: C++ is a fine language indeed. And it isn't hard either. But i guess for this situation i would not choose it even if the code was almost complete. For the reason, that the client **will** ask for alterations, which can end up as a lot of changes in someone else's code (do they get the source? Or it a library?). Not to mention, that in a lot of cases where performance is not that big an issue, the best language is the one you know the most.
Still <3 C :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Thomas says (which is all true), your hosting company will most likely prohibit running custom binaries. Hosting packages short of virtual private server normally don't allow user-written compiled code on the Web server, only scripts.

VPS hosting is, on average, 5 times as expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write the C++ code in PHP. You can also convert C++ to Java using a [converter](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CPlusPlus_to_Java_Converter_Details.html) and then use the Java virtual machine if your host allows that. You can use the C++ code if your host allows that. You can host the C++ code from a local machine if that is a good idea in your case.

I would tell the client that in case there is no explicit need for the C++ language I would go with implementing PHP. You know, the communication between C++ and PHP adds to server load even if the host allows you to use the C++ module. And in the future you will have a lot of pain maintain